# Create a calculation in a table visual, not in underlying data

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In a previous Power Bi dashboard I was working on, I created a variable called "Percent of Planned Pace".  It showed whether or not a study protocol was accruing patients as fast as it was supposed to.

Lets take an imaginary scenario like this:

- Study named LS-P-Joe
- Total target patients: 100
- Total years planned:    10,
  So 10 patients per year
- Months since activation: 24 (2 years)
- Total    patients enrolled so far 15

So in this case its real simple, since its 100 patients over 10 years, that means we're expecting ten per year.  Its been 2 years, so we'd expect 20 so far... but we're at 15 so we're a little behind the pace.

In a previous dashboard (and underlying dataset in power query) I created the "percent of planned pace" variable with this:
[image]

Well that works great when its one data source that I can add a column to.

**My problem now** is that my data no longer comes from one source.  It comes from several.  So I need to create a measure or something that calculates this for each row in my visual, but each column might be from a different query:

[image]

In this example from above, I've added in parenthesis what each variable is called and what dataset it is from.  How can I calculate this for my visual?

- Study named LS-P-Joe (rv_protocol_basic:protocol_no)
- Total target patients: 100  (rv_protocol_dtl_accrual_info:protocol_target_accrual)
- Total years planned:    10  (rv_protocol_dtl_accrual_info:total_years_planned)
  So 10 per year
- Months since activation: 24 (2 years)   (rv_protocol_basic:months_since_activation)
- Total    patients enrolled so far 15   (rv_protocol_basic: accrual_to_date)

Comment: Sounds like you need a Measure, which is calculated on the fly based on the current filter context and row context. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-measures

Comment: Thank you.  I looked into measures a little bit for this before posting, I should have included that but I didnt want to overwhelm the question.  I tried this:  Measure = ((12*'rv_protocol_basic'[ACCRUAL_TO_DATE])/'rv_protocol_basic'[sv_protocol_status.Protocol.Months Since Activation])/('rv_protocol_dtl_accrual_info'[protocol_target_accrual]/'rv_protocol_dtl_accrual_info'[total_years_planned])*100)   but I can tell its wildly wrong because there's a bunch of red lines with "cannot find name".  Is there something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this kind of thing when I did cancer research. From my experience, it would be much easier of you had these tables in your model:

1. Study (StudyID, YearsPlanned, TargetPatients, ActivationDate)
2. a child table for Enrollment (PatientID, StudyID, EnrollDate...), and
3. a Calendar table just for good measure (in case you need to filter by date ranges etc)

Measures:
Enroll Count = COUNTROWS('Enrolls')
% of Goal =
DIVIDE ([Enroll Count],CALCULATE(MIN([Target Patients])),BLANK())

If you're doing a running sum of enrollments (I assume that's what you mean by accrual in this case), You can create a measure like
CALCULATE ([Enroll Count],
FILTER(ALL('DimDate'),DimDate[Date]<=MAX(DimDate[Date])))

and you should get a running total of enrollments over time.

Comment: Thank you for helping!  I must admit I'm a tiny bit confused, I must not have explained the situation well.

I dont have any patient specific data (i.e. patientID, enrolldate, etc).   I only have info about total subjects on protocols and stuff like that.

As far as the calendar table, makes sense and I have done stuff like that for other dashboards, but not sure its relevant to the particular question I'm asking is it?

And I dont need a running total of enrollments over time, I just need that percent of pace.  I have all the other variables ready to go.

Comment: If you're just doing a "percent of total", then the measure is like this:
DIVIDE ( [measure name], CALCULATE( [measure name], ALL('DimDate') )

Comment: Thank you again for staying with me on this, I'm sorry for my confusion but I really do appreciate it.  I dont really understand the dimdate involvement.  The only 'time' involvement is from two columns that already exist.  One is just a simple numeric "how many years planned" so it'll be a number like 1,2,3,4,etc...    and one is another numeric of 'how many months has it been open' so like 12,16,24, etc..

So I totally get how I would do a measure that was 'percent of total' by dividing the accrued by target accrual, but I dont know how to incorporate the two columns just mentioned.

Comment: did you try creating a calculated column = [accrued]/[target total]?
It may be as simple as that.

Comment: No thats what I'm saying above, I understand that part, but thats only half the problem.  I need to do (accrual/months since activation)/(target accrual/number of years planned) but across different queries and I'm lost on the 'grammar' of how to point to different queries

Comment: What do you mean by "different queries"? Do you mean different data sources (if so, are they union compatible <same number of rows, same/compatible data types>?) If so, you can use Append in PowerQuery to create one long table. Otherwise, you can use UNION(table1, table2) to do it. Then you base your report on that and hide the <table1>,<table2>...<tableN> in your model.

The whole accrual thing is trivial if you have a column in your table that you can use for the sequencing.
Can you give an example of your tables that contain the same data? Unless I'm missing something, use PowerQuery.